# How can I send JSON data and file to server using ajax or simple form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form with a file upload. I also have an array of objects that I want to send beside form data and file. but I can't have both at the same time.

How can I send file and an array of json data to server using ajax? If I add property "multipart/form-data" to simple form, and not use ajax, how can I attach an array of objects to my form before submit? Iterating through that array and adding it with append to `formData` doesn't work.

Comment: formData is the correct way. show your code. dont add irrelevant tags.